# C# GC for Server

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

Is Server GC (gcServer flag in configuration) available in .Net 4.0? Or it was deprecated?

Thank you!!!

Comment: The flag doesn't appear to be deprecated (30 seconds with google). Perhaps you should instead describe why you're thinking of using it, or an actual problem you're experiencing that you think might be solved by it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's (still available). No, it isn't (deprecated).

Why the question?

A link on the argument http://architecturebyashwani.blogspot.com/2010/02/foreground-gc-and-background-gc.html

There is even a new GC (background for workstation mode) in 4.0, so in the end there are three GC; server, workstation concurrent on, workstation concurrent off.

The three settings for `web.config`/`app.config` are:

```xml
<configuration> 
    <runtime> 
        <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/> 
<!-- or -->
        <gcConcurrent enabled="true"/> 
<!-- or -->
        <gcServer enabled="true"/> 
    </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

The three `or` are "exclusive". You can enable only ONE option at a time :-)

Comment: As of 4.5 you can enable both