# C# performance varying due to memory

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory, memory-management

Hope this is a valid post here, its a combination of C# issues and hardware.

I am benchmarking our server because we have found problems with the performance of our quant library (written in C#). I have simulated the same performance issues with some simple C# code- performing very heavy memory-usage.

The code below is in a function which is spawned from a threadpool, up to a maximum of 32 threads (because our server has 4x CPUs x 8 cores each).

This is all on .Net 3.5

The problem is that we are getting wildly differing performance. I run the below function 1000 times. The average time taken for the code to run could be, say, 3.5s, but the fastest will only be 1.2s and the slowest will be 7s- for the exact same function!

I have graphed the memory usage against the timings and there doesnt appear to be any correlation with the GC kicking in.

One thing I did notice is that when running in a single thread the timings are identical and there is no wild deviation. I have also tested CPU-bound algorithms and the timings are identical too. This has made us wonder if the memory bus just cannot cope.

I was wondering could this be another .net or C# problem, or is it something related to our hardware? Would this be the same experience if I had used C++, or Java?? We are using 4x Intel x7550 with 32GB ram. Is there any way around this problem in general?

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
List<byte> list1 = new List<byte>();
List<byte> list2 = new List<byte>();
List<byte> list3 = new List<byte>();


int Size1 = 10000000;
int Size2 = 2 * Size1;
int Size3 = Size1;

for (int i = 0; i < Size1; i++)
{
    list1.Add(57);
}

for (int i = 0; i < Size2; i = i + 2)
{
    list2.Add(56);
}

for (int i = 0; i < Size3; i++)
{
    byte temp = list1.ElementAt(i);
    byte temp2 = list2.ElementAt(i);
    list3.Add(temp);
    list2[i] = temp;
    list1[i] = temp2;
}
watch.Stop();
```

(the code is just meant to stress out the memory)

I would include the threadpool code, but we used a non-standard threadpool library.

EDIT: I have reduced "size1" to 100000, which basically doesn't use much memory and I still get a lot of jitter. This suggests it's not the amount of memory being transferred, but the frequency of memory grabs?

Comment: Are any other processes running during your benchmark?  Even the OS needs CPU time.  If you're using all virtual cores during your benchmark, you're virtually (pardon the pun) guaranteed that non-related processes will take CPU time during your test.

Comment: We don't have enough information to do anything but speculate.  That said, my money is on your "non-standard threadpool library" not allocating enough threads to run this in parallel.  If you run 50 copies and you only allocate 20 threads (for example), 10 iterations are going to have to wait (on average) for 2 other iterations to complete for a thread to free up.  That could account for the deviations that you are seeing.

Comment: Just an idea: Since you appear to know the size of the list, you should pass that to the constructor  (or just use arrays). Then you avoid the re-allocations if the underlying arrays.

Comment: Is there any synchronisation between the threads?

Comment: +1 on Brian Rasmussen's suggestion: you are probably spending a whole lot of time on memory allocation and moving stuff around.

Comment: Are you using concurrent GC?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423951/c-sharp-gc-for-server

Comment: @Eric J. Nope this is the only process running on Windows Server 2008 .

Comment: @Chris, I sometimes see the "slower" function durations grouped together. For example I could have 5ms, 5ms, 5ms, 5ms, 17ms, 18ms, 16ms, 5ms, 5ms, 5ms, 6ms, 4ms, 5ms.....

Comment: @Slugart, all the threads are totally independent and not locking on anything.

Comment: Are you running consistently in Debug/Release mode?  GC behaves differently depending on the build mode.

Comment: In addition to Brian's suggestion of setting the initial capacity for the Lists you should also look into object pooling: allocating all the objects for the maximum number of threads that you will start up and then re-using those objects throughout the life of the process.

Comment: Here's my suggestion. Go back and try to create some code that demonstrates this behavior in a reproducible way. Without that, I don't think you are going to get anything but conjecture here.

Comment: How many threads are you spawning this process in?  If you're doing the max 32 (4CPUs x 8cores), you might want to drop just a couple to allow the operating system to perform its background services/work without interfering.  Also, see what happens when you only pool a couple or using the standard .NET thread pooling mechanisms (rather than the non-standard library)

Comment: @Chris Sinclair, I have tested with 1,2,4,8,16 and 32 threads and everything above 1 shows the same "randomness".

Comment: @Chris Shain, I would have done that initially if it wasn't for this threadpool library we used. I will see what I can do.

Comment: @KristoferA-Huagati.com: most time is spent in `Array.Copy` :)

Comment: is hyper threading enabled? Could it be causing the variance by threads being placed in virtual processors and not actual cores?

Comment: also your processors clock speed is sometimes lower due to the turbo boost function of the processor

Answer (score 4):

There isn't enough to go on, but here are some areas to start looking:

- The variability is the result of internal GC state. The GC dynamically manages the sizes of the various pools. If you start with different pool sizes, you'll get different GC behavior during runs.
- Moire patterns in the thread scheduling. Depending on random variations in the sequencing of the threads, you could have more or less favorable patterns of contention. If there's any periodicity, that may lead to an amplified effect akin to constructive interference.
- False sharing. If you have two threads that both hit memory addresses that are close enough as to be colocated in the processor cache, you'll see a marked decrease in performance as the processors have to spend a lot of time re-synching their caches. Depending on how you organize your data and allocate threads to process it, you may get patterns in false sharing based on variations at the start.
- Another process in the system is taking up processor time. You might want to use a measure of process user mode time instead of wall-time. (There's an accessor to that in the Process class somewhere).
- The machine is running close to it's full physical memory limit. Swapping to disk is occurring with a more-or-less random pattern.

Comment: #3 is commonly called [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Comment: @RonWarholic Thanks. I knew there was a term for it, just couldn't remember.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting pretty fundamental machine limitations here.  You have a lot of cores but there is still only one memory bus.  So if your threads do a lot of data shuffling then they are likely to get throttled by the bandwidth of that single bus.  This is Amdahl's law at work.

There is one possible optimization, it depends on the type of operating system this machine runs.  This is server kind of hardware but if you have a non-server version of Windows then the garbage collector will run in workstation mode.  You can then use the `<gcServer>` element in the app's .config file to ask for the server version of the collector.  It uses multiple heaps so the threads won't fight for the GC heap lock as often when they allocate memory.  Ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

List uses arrays internally for storage.  I believe it will attempt to double the size of the array each time it reaches the limit of free space in the List.

As you go into the loop, it needs larger and larger chunks of contiguous memory to allocate the new arrays as the list grows.  With one thread, this is pretty easy. With 2+ threads, you are competing for large chunks of contiguous memory.  It would trigger the GC at random times as the arrays got larger and contiguous memory was harder to find.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the Lists for pre-determined sizes byte[], where the size is 10,000,000 and the times for the function to complete are still completely random. Fastest is 462ms, Average is 1192ms and slowest is 2509ms- more than double the average.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the runtime config has gcserver=true

Comment: Investigated that- it made the process average faster but didn't reduce the variation in times.

Comment: I would be interested to see the results of using parallel.for in your code to see the impact asynchronous calls make

Answer (score 0):

At this point it seems like guessing anything would simply be conjecture. Really what you need is more information.

I would hook up a profiler or setup some Windows performance counters:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300504

You should be able to add some performance counters centered on the process. You can look at how many threads are being spun up, memory utilization, etc. I would take some of the other suggestions here and measure the scenario you are looking for. If you dump the performance counter data to a csv file you can even graph the results pretty quickly to get some good data to actually chew on. If you can find what metric is changing with the 1.2s vs 7s scenario you can begin making some educated guesses as to what's going on, and continue to hone in.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous calls to shared resources, like the Console or the File System, will significantly degrade the performance, but by the looks of things, this code is just maxing CPU and the time variances must be due to other processes requesting CPU time.